# PHP with UTF8 output into PHPExcel?

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm having an issue with exporting data from a utf8 mysql database into an excel sheet with PHPExcel and retaining chinese characters.  My mysql db is utf8 and has numerous chinese characters in it, and I'm exporting that data into a multi-sheet xls file (excel5) and every export the chinese characters turn into "?".  I've tried utf8_encode() but it doesn't work for me.  I also tried changing the output to excel2007 thinking it would be an excel5 writer issue.

Is there a way to get Chinese characters to export correctly?
Do I have to make the entire php file utf8? and if so how would I go about doing so?

Here is the portion I'm having issue with:

```
$res2 = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$sheetnametemp);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  $counter = 2;
  $cell = $coltemp;
  $cell .= $counter;
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($cell, $row2[0]);
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$sheetnametemp);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $counter++;
        $cell2 = $coltemp;
        $cell2 .= $counter;
        utf8_encode($row[$row2[0]]);
        echo "<br />";
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($cell2,utf8_encode($row[$row2[0]]));
      }
```

I need to use those chinese characters as it is a multi-lingual catalog db so changing it to english wouldn't help.  Also I am currently on a Mac with Xampp if that info is helpful in anyway.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Sorry I forgot, I'm so used to mysql but I usually change it to mysqli when finalizing the program, maybe I'll try out PDO and thanks for the references.  But you think that may be the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't need to make any changes at all to UTF-8 data when setting cell values: PHPExcel expects all string content to be UTF-8. Are you setting your executing "SET NAMES utf8" or mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn); to ensure that your connection to the database is using UTF-8? You can test the connection using echo mysql_client_encoding($conn);

Comment: Oh wow, did not do that.  Just tried it and yes it works thanks! but it rose a different issue, instead of question marks it is now something like this : "é¦¬ç¹å©èå¸¦å¹²éä¸ç¾å¨å¹´ééç" and not chinese characters like this "馬爹利藍带干邑一百周年". i set the mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn); right below the connection line.  any idea why this is? Is there a way to set collation too? or is that not needed?

Comment: An Excel file uses a codepage to identify the character set being used within the file, but PHPExcel sets that coepage to a hard-coded value of UTF-8 internally, so all string content in the file should be UTF-8, and Excel knows to interpret the worksheets in the MS Excel GUI as UTF-8 as well. If you're not seeing chinese characters when you look at the spreadsheet in Excel itself, then check the language settings in MS Excel to see if it's configured to handle chinese

Comment: Also make sure that you're not trying to call utf8_encode() anymore within your code

Comment: From your suggestion, utf8_encode() was the issue with that issue. Thanks for your help @MarkBaker!!

Answer (score 4):

Setting your executing "SET NAMES utf8" or mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn); to ensure that your connection to the database is using UTF-8.

You can test the connection using echo mysql_client_encoding($conn);

Make sure that you're not trying to call utf8_encode() anymore either.

Note: An Excel file uses a codepage to identify the character set being used within the file, but PHPExcel sets that codepage to a hard-coded value of UTF-8 internally, so all string content in the file should be UTF-8, and Excel knows to interpret the worksheets in the MS Excel GUI as UTF-8 as well. If you're not seeing chinese characters when you look at the spreadsheet in Excel itself, then check the language settings in MS Excel to see if it's configured to handle chinese

Credit: [@Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker).
Thanks again.